# FileInputstream + NullPointerException while File is present and readable

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, inputstream

probably a simple Problem, with a one-sentecne-Solution^^: How can .load() give me a NullPointerException?

```
    File ksFile=new File(kspath);
    Log.d("kspath", kspath);
    FileInputStream is=null;
    is = new FileInputStream(ksFile/*kspath*/);
    if(is==null)
        Log.d("debug", "Oh no!");

    if(ksFile.isFile())
        Log.d("debug", "ok");
    if(ksFile.canRead())
        Log.d("debug", "ok");

    if("".toCharArray()==null)
        Log.d("debug", "Oh no!");

    keyStore.load(is, kspw.toCharArray());
```

As you can see is added ridiculous checks, i get 2 "ok"s und no "oh no!"s
the problem is the Inputstream, but why^^?
if i try reading from the Stream with 
`while((is.read(byte[] somevar))!=-1)` it actually reads.

EDIT:

I am an idiot, forgot to add keyStore.getinstance(), nevermind, i'm tired, thanks to gkuzmin^^

Comment: is `keyStore` variable value `null`?

Comment: thank you i am an idiot, forgot to add keyStore.getinstance()^^

Comment: may be error inside your  keyStore.load() method

Comment: you should post your own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in this way:

```
    keyStore = keyStore.getinstance();

    if((keyStore != null) && (kspath != null)) {
       File ksFile = new File(kspath);

       FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(ksFile);

       keyStore.load(is, kspw.toCharArray());
    }
```

But without object definition of `keystore` variable, is difficult understand if keystore is null or other variable.

Keep us posted.

Answer (score -3):

hey you have to specify  file path as a parameter for  FileInputStream not a file name
so it should be like this

```
    is = new FileInputStream(ksFile.getPath());
```

Comment: No he doesn't! FileInputStream [accepts File as a parameter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream%28java.io.File%29).